# How to access Amazon Redshift by @aws-sdk/client-redshift-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-sdk

I developed sample apps which backend DB is Redshift and try to execute query by following SDK code.

```
import { RedshiftDataClient, ExecuteStatementCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-redshift-data';


export const resolvers: IResolvers<unknown, Context> = {
  Query: {
    user: (parent, args, context): User => ({ login: context.login }),
    region: (): string => getRegion(),
    getData: async () => {
      const redshift_client = new RedshiftDataClient({});
      
      const request = new ExecuteStatementCommand({
        ClusterIdentifier: 'testrs',
        Sql: `select * from test`,
        SecretArn: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:12345561:secret:test-HYRSWs',
        Database: 'test',
      });

      try {
        const data = await redshift_client.send(request);
        console.log('data', data);
        return data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error('Failed fetching data to Redshift');
      } finally {
        // execute regardless of error state
      }
    },
  },
};
```

It returned following error

```
ERROR   AccessDeniedException: 
User: arn:aws:sts::12345561:assumed-role/WebsiteStack-Beta-US-EAST-GraphQLLambdaServiceRole1BCPB5P3Q4IS9/GraphQLLambda 
is not authorized to perform: redshift-data:ExecuteStatement on resource: arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:12345561:cluster:testrs 
because no identity-based policy allows the redshift-data:ExecuteStatement action
```

Must I use sdk package like `STS` ?

If someone has opinion,or materials. will you please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know when using the AWS SDK for Java V2 for the exact same use case, you can successfully query data by setting the **ExecuteStatementRequest** object and passing it to the Data Client's executeStatement like this:

```
if (num ==5)
       sqlStatement = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM blog ORDER BY date DESC";
 else if (num ==10)
       sqlStatement = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM blog ORDER BY date DESC";
  else
       sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY date DESC" ;

   ExecuteStatementRequest statementRequest = ExecuteStatementRequest.builder()
                .clusterIdentifier(clusterId)
                .database(database)
                .dbUser(dbUser)
                .sql(sqlStatement)
                .build();

   ExecuteStatementResponse response = redshiftDataClient.executeStatement(statementRequest);
```

As shown here --  the required values are **clusterId**, **database**, and **dbUser**.

I would assume the AWS SDK for JavaScript would work the same way. (I have not tried using that SDK however).

The reference docs confirm this...

**Temporary credentials** - when connecting to a cluster, specify the cluster identifier, the database name, and the database user name. Also, permission to call the redshift:GetClusterCredentials operation is required. When connecting to a serverless endpoint, specify the database name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-redshift-data/classes/executestatementcommand.html